# QGridLayout Widget disappearing after using QAlignment

Tags: qt, qgridlayout

I have the following:

```
QGridLayout *layout = new GridLayout();
layout->addWidget(rightBuf, row, 0);
layout->addWidget(i, row, 1);
layout->addWidget(leftBuf, row, 2);
```

Which displays fiine. However, when I add the alignment to the second line, ie:

```
layout->addWidget(i, row, 1, Qt::AlignTop);
```

The widget disappears from the screen. I think I have tried about just everything to get it to align top, including putting it into a QVBoxLayout and then adding it to the QGridLayout. Is there anything missing here?

Comment: Did you forget to pass in a widget into the constructor for `QGridLayout` or did you just simplify the code that you provided above?

Comment: I did. Not sure what I should pass to the constructor...I have a main display, and a widget I'm trying to display within that display, using a grid layout. Do I pass the main window display as the constructor? I tried both, and this time, it appears as a separate window

Comment: Construct the main window and the widget as you are doing now.  Add the widget as the central widget on the main window using `QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`.  Then use the widget as the parent for the `QGridLayout`.